# npm error when installing phonegap

Tags: cordova, ubuntu, npm

Please help me to install phonegap in ubuntu.

I have already installed node , but its showing npm missing...

```
syam@shyam-Veriton-Series:~$ npm install -g phonegap
The program 'npm' is currently not installed. To run 'npm' please ask your administrator to install the package 'npm'
```

Comment: I edited your question and title to closer reflect the problem and the style expected here at SO. I hope one of the answers solved your problem, if so please upvote / accept.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install nodeJS first, then npm, and then you can install phonegap:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install npm
npm install -g phonegap
```

Comment: Am getting npm package missing error again and again, why its showing like this, Is i need to change any folder permissions..

Comment: @user2145351 - Which version of Ubuntu are you on?

Answer (score 0):

You say you have installed node, however you haven't installed `npm`.

I assume you installed node like this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

npm can be installed in the same way:

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

This [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server) has a full guide to installing Node.js on Ubuntu.

Once you have installed `npm`, you should be able to install phonegap using your original command:

```
 npm install -g phonegap
```

Comment: Hi,  Am getting an error on npm  ....    syam@shyam-Veriton-Series:~$ sudo apt-get install npm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

Comment: In that case, it is probably time to [askUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com), which as luck would have it, is part of the SE network.

Comment: one doubt.. after installing npm is i need to anything like this ?  sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

Comment: @SyamkumarKK I wouldn't expect so